# Yii2 REST update extraFields

Tags: php, rest, api, yii2

I have used the extraFields method to include fields from a related model inside an ApiController. Is it possible to update the default model attributes of the controller as well as the extra fields from relation by overriding the update action?

Comment: An update will only set the "default" model attributes. Any extra attributes related to other models are not handled (from what I can tell). You need to handle that with a custom method, something similar to yii\rest\UpdateAction, I would suggest.

Comment: Thank you - I have done it with a custom method was just checking there wasn't an easier/better way to do it